# How to display multiline paragraph texts in a button, using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Is there any CSS trick to display multiline text paragraphs in a button control. I don't want "pre" tag or Javascript solutions, because I will have a large number of button widgets!,
The below code is for your convenience:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Single Line Buttons</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn">This should be a multiline Button containing sevaral lines of text like a paragraph</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're enclosing paragraphs (or even a single paragraph) in a `<button>` I suspect you're using `<button>` elements wrong.

Comment: If by 'button' you mean your anchor element; then [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)?

Comment: By 'button' you mean 'Some area where the user can click/tap and launch an action?'

Comment: I don't want to use pre or br tags etc, due to large number of buttons. I want CSS trick I think may be display: block etc.

Comment: Yes Pablo Martinez, You thought right. But I don't want to make links etc!

Comment: could you not just do it in a div and put an onclick handler on it ? Like this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qe9ag3yx/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example code, just add the CSS:

```
.ui-btn {
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The normal white-space allows the text to wrap, while the text-align gives a standard left aligned paragraph. If you want to keep the center alignment, just remove text-align from the CSS.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmvmgrth/)**

Comment: Yes This is the solution, Thanks Mr. Ezanker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the white-space css property if the text has line breaks like you want it.

```
.ui-btn { white-space: pre; }
```

Though, your selector may have to be more specific to override the default jquery-mobile styles.

Ex:

```
.ui-content .ui-btn { white-space: pre; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e00889yz/

Update:

The issue here is that jquery mobile's stylesheet defines white-space to be nowrap for the "ui-btn" class. So you have to override that property with a more specific css selector or the "!important" flag with either white-space pre (if your text already has line breaks) or as ezanker noted, white-space normal (if it does not have predefined linebreaks)

http://jsfiddle.net/e00889yz/1/

Comment: This is same as pre tag!, I have to enter Carriage Return in every text paragraph manually:(. I want the text should fit automatically the whole space available in mobile/tablet device etc

Comment: I understand, but please read the updated section. Using white-space normal is not like a pre tag.

Comment: OK, Thanks Mr. Wet Noodles. Ezanker solution is accepted now.